# Do the first digits of the Fibonacci numbers form a pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Does the sequence of first digits of the Fibonacci numbers form some sort of regular pattern eventually? Is there anything interesting we can say about them?

I know the last digit repeats after 60, and have been delving into the pisano period for different values of n, but that got me wondering about the first digit.

Comment: Not much is known, other than the obey the [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), as one would expect.

Comment: There's some information here: https://oeis.org/A008963 . But no mention of periodicity or an obvious pattern.

Comment: With the exception of the very start of the sequence, there is always four or five digits in non-descending order. Starting with one or two 1s and a 2.

Comment: The distribution of the first digit of a sequence is equivalent to the mod-1 distribution of the base-10 logarithm of that sequence; and the logarithm of the Fibonacci sequence is essentially a linear sequence.

Comment: For every given finite digit string (first digit not $0$) , we can find a Fibonacci-number starting with this digit string.